# VBA - process runs correctly on my computer, but not on another

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT 2 - Solved by Comintern - the missed definition here -

```
Rows(r.Row + counter & ":" & r.Row + counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Should read

```
ws.Rows(r.Row + counter & ":" & r.Row + counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Original Post - 
I have a tool I'm trying to make with the main primary functions -

- Basic reformatting to a report
- Splitting rows where a single cell has a,b,c,d into 4 rows with one value each
- Row deletion or recolouring based on value in column H
- File saving

It runs fine on my computer, and it runs fine on a colleagues computer when going step-by-step. However, running the code on my colleagues computer, everything runs but the output is different.
***~Edit***  I was running step-by-step remote on a colleague's PC whilst going step-by-step on my own PC, to confirm output looked the same

I've checked around, and not able to work out what is causing this issue.

Code is run from a button, so don't believe it's an issue with activesheet. Additionally, I think I've linked every range/reference to a named worksheet. Also, I'm not hitting an error, simply it is giving a different output (specifically, more rows are deleted in the output)

```
Sub FDA_Macro_Clean()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, outputwb As Workbook
Dim lastrow As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim rownum As Long, rownum2 As Long, string1 As Long, string2 As Long, counter As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim timeslot As String, shareddrive As String, savename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'turns off alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turns off screen updates

'###################################### - Defines Workbook and Sheets
Set wb = Workbooks("FDA Macro Template - No GRID 11-28 2pm.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Import Declaration Report")

'###################################### - Delete unused cells
ws.Rows("1:56").Delete
ws.Range("A:B,Q:Q").Delete

'###################################### - defines final active row (1 of 3 times we define)

lastrow = ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'###################################### - Delete s cells which are out of scope

x = 2
Do Until x = lastrow + 1

    If ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "APH - MAY PROCEED" Or ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "FDA - " Then
        ws.Range("H" & x).EntireRow.Delete 'Deletes rows with above 2 criteria values
        x = x - 1
    End If
    x = x + 1

Loop

'###################################### - Creates new rows for anything where column A/B has different values
rownum = 1
Do Until ws.Range("A" & rownum) = ""
    string1 = UBound(Split(ws.Range("A" & rownum), ",")) 'counts instances of "," in Column A
    string2 = UBound(Split(ws.Range("B" & rownum), ",")) 'counts instances of "," in Column B

    If string1 <> string2 Or string1 = 0 Then   'if the strings are 0, skip to next item. If strings mismatch, follow error path
        If string1 <> string2 Then 'If strings mismatch, follow error path
            ws.Range("A" & rownum & ":N" & rownum).Interior.Color = RGB(236, 110, 212) 'ERROR PATH - Highlight Purple
            ws.Range("M" & rownum).Value = ws.Range("M" & rownum).Value & "Bill/Container count mismatch" 'ERROR PATH - Add comment in column M
            y = y + 1 'Value of Y is used to determine if there is an error later in the macro
        End If
        rownum = rownum + 1 'Next row
        GoTo NextRowLoop                                        'increases RowNum by 1 and skips the split
    End If

    'Part 2 - only for lines where String1 <> 0 and String1 = String2

    Set r = ws.Range("a" & rownum)       'sets r to current cell - CBL column
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(r, ", ")                                             'fills array with each bill, removing the ", "
    r = arr(0)                                                          'puts the first array value in Range 'A&r'
    For counter = 1 To UBound(arr)              'adds a counter from 1 to UBound
        Rows(r.Row + counter & ":" & r.Row + counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown                  'inserts a new row
        r.Offset(counter, 0) = arr(counter)      'puts each additional Array entry in a row added below (because location is tied to 'counter', the gap increases by one each loop)
    Next counter
    Erase arr                                                           'clears the array

    Set r = ws.Range("b" & rownum)                  'sets range to current cell - Container column
    arr = Split(r, ", ")                                              'fills array with each bill, removing the ", "
    r = arr(0)                                                            'puts the first array value in Range 'B&r'
    For counter = 1 To UBound(arr)
        r.Offset(counter, 0) = arr(counter)         'puts each additional Array entry in a row added below (because location is tied to 'counter', the gap increases by one each loop)
        ws.Range(r.Offset(counter, 1), r.Offset(counter, 12)).Value = ws.Range(r.Offset(counter - 1, 1), r.Offset(counter, 12)).Value 'fills all other report data down for columns C-N
    Next counter
    Erase arr            'clears the array

    rownum = rownum + counter       'adds the counter value to the rownum value, so we don't look in the new lines we created

NextRowLoop:                     'bookmark which links to the String1 / String2 IF argument
Loop

'###################################### - redefine lastrow (2 of 3 times we define)

lastrow = ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'###################################### - Delete rows, or recolour rows based on PGA Status Description

x = 2
Do Until x = lastrow + 1
    If ws.Range("H" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(236, 110, 212) Then 'FInds rows already PURPLE
        GoTo NextRowLoop2 'if row colour is purple, skip
    ElseIf ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "FDA - MAY PROCEED" Or ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "FDA - MAY PROCEED; APH - MAY PROCEED" Or ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "APH - MAY PROCEED; FDA - MAY PROCEED" Then
        ws.Range("A" & x & ":N" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(129, 235, 111) 'sets rows with above criteria to GREEN
    ElseIf Left(ws.Range("H" & x).Value, 20) = "FDA - DATA UNDER PGA" Then
        ws.Range("A" & x & ":N" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'sets rows with above criteria to YELLOW
    ElseIf ws.Range("H" & x).Value = "FDA - Hold Intact" Then
        ws.Range("A" & x & ":N" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'sets rows with above criteria to RED
    End If
NextRowLoop2:
    x = x + 1
Loop

'###################################### - sorts based on colour Purple > Red > Yellow > Green

With ws.Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add(ws.Range("A2"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(236, 110, 212)
        .Add(ws.Range("A2"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(129, 235, 111)
        .Add(ws.Range("A2"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Add(ws.Range("A2"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Add Key:=ws.Range("C2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'###################################### - Reformatting for selected columns and autofits cells
ws.Range("C2:D" & lastrow, "I2:J" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" 'sets date format in date cells
ws.Range("E2:F" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "General" 'sets general format for Entry Port and Entry Number
ws.Columns("A:N").AutoFit 'autofit columns
ws.Rows("1:" & lastrow).EntireRow.AutoFit 'autofit rows

'###################################### - Creates a new workbook and moves just the output sheet
Set outputwb = Workbooks.Add
ws.Copy Before:=outputwb.Sheets(1)
outputwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete

'###################################### - Error Path - cleans the Macro workbook and promts user to fix Purple rows. Exit sub without saving file (needs manual saving)
If y > 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'turns on alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turns on screen updates

    ws.Cells.ClearContents
    ws.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone

    MsgBox "Workbook has " & y & " lines where Number of Bills in Column A does not match Number of Containers in Column B. " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Rows still requiring rework are highlighted Purple, and comment added to Column M." _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "All other rows have been processed" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Macro will now exit. Once reworked, please manually save."

    Exit Sub
End If

'###################################### - Zero Error Path - cleans the Macro workbook
ws.Cells.ClearContents
ws.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone

'###################################### - 'Saves file based on the Time we're running it

If Time() < TimeValue("13:29:00") Then
    timeslot = "(Morning)"
ElseIf Time() < TimeValue("16:19:00") Then
    timeslot = "(Midday)"
Else: timeslot = "(Afternoon)"
End If

shareddrive = "X:\HD Folders\HD-FDA REPORTS\DAILY FDA SHIPMENT REPORT\"
savename = "DAILY FDA SHIPMENT REPORT " & Format(Now(), ("mm.dd.yy")) & " " & timeslot
outputwb.SaveAs shareddrive & savename & ".xlsx"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'turns on alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turns on screen updates

End Sub
```

Anyone able to save me?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Andy! Have you tried stepping through your code using `F8`? You may be able to pinpoint where issues are happening by starting there. Another suggestion is to remove the lines `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` so you can see - in real time - what exactly is happening.

Comment: Hey! I have gone step by step, remote on my colleagues computer (F5 through the loops once I established each one looked correct). The end result matched what my computer produces. However, when I then ran the macro in full, it produced a different result

Comment: Please see [MCVE].  As is this too broad.  Try to find the offending part and create a smaller block of code that represents the error.  It should be something we can test.

Comment: You should be looping backward when deleting rows. Also, this line needs a worksheet qualifier: `Rows(r.Row + counter & ":" & r.Row + counter).Insert Shift:=xlDown`.

Comment: Both are great shouts, thanks